# Error connecting to IdentityServer from container. SSL connection could not be established

Tags: .net, docker, duende-identity-server

**I can try connecting to IdentityServer container from other container on discovery endpoint over HTTPS**

IdentityServer project was generated from template:

```
dotnet new isinmem
```

I'm only added container support in project, with config:

```
ports:
      - "5000:80"
      - "5001:443"
```

Client project is template console app, with code:

```
using IdentityModel.Client;

var client = new HttpClient();
var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://host.docker.internal:5001");
Console.WriteLine(disco.Error);
Console.WriteLine(disco.TokenEndpoint);
```

docker-compose.override.yml for IdentityServer and Client:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  webapplication3:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=password
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/host.docker.internal.pfx
    ports:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
```

When I run client, he return error message:

```
Error connecting to https://host.docker.internal:5001/.well-known/openid-configuration. The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception..
```

Although if you go to the discovery endpoint page in the browser or via curl, it works correctly.
One important detail, as long as the client does not add to the container, everything works fine.

I tried generate self-signed certificates, it didn't help either.

Comment: `see inner exception`

Comment: Ok i'm find inner exception `The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot`. How to set up the container correctly?

Comment: The simplest would probably be to install the CA in the Trusted container, but my Docker experience is not good enough for me to guide you on that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution, but I don't like copying rootCA.crt to the project folder. Maybe you will have suggestions to fix it:

1. download [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) and created a new local CA

```
mkcert -install
```

2. copy file rootCA.pem from `mkcert -CAROOT` folder into project, rename him in rootCA.crt and in Dockerfile add

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
ADD <name_service>/rootCA.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/rootCA.crt
RUN chmod 644 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/rootCA.crt && update-ca-certificates
...
```

3. create cert.pfx with default password 'changeit' and copy him into `~/.aspnet/https/` folder

```
mkcert -p12-file cert.pfx -pkcs12 host.docker.internal localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1
```

4. add in docker-compose.override.yml

```
services:
  <name_service>:
    environment:
      ...
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=changeit
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/cert.pfx
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__AllowInvalid=true
      ...
    volumes:
      ...
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
```